# _encode in setConfig in AccessControlledOffchainAggregator

Tags: chainlink

In the smart contract set for the OffchainReporting, there is in the deployed contract "AccessControllerOffchainAggregator" the field setConfig which asks for _encode.

What do I encode here and how do I encode it?